# Entity Framework override SaveChanges() on Service layer instead of Data layer (different projects)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

My ASP.NET WebAPI application has Data & Service layer, multiple projects in one solution.

```
Data Layer (Entity Framework)
-DbContext.cs

Service Layer (Business Logic)
-Controller.cs
-Global.asax
```

One of my entities requires business logic intercept every time it run DbContext  SaveChanges().

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        BusinessLogicAndUpdateEntity(); //Code from Service Layer
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Currently the business logic resides in service layer, and data project can't reference service layer project else the project will be circular referencing each other.

Is there a way for me to override DbContext SaveChanges() in service layer without moving my business logic to the data layer?

Comment: I think the controller should be the middleman here. DAL shoudn't notify BL. The controller should notify both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fire an event in MyDbContext (maybe it already exists in DbContext?)

```
public delegate void BeforeSaveChangesSignature ();
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public event BeforeSaveChangesSignature BeforeSaveChanges {get; set;}

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        BeforeSaveChanges?.Invoke(); 
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Your business logic would then subscribe the event, and performing whatever they need:

```
...
var context = new MyDbContext();
context.BeforeSaveChanges  += () => { Console.WriteLine("Before save"); }
...
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Is that possible to attach the event globally? as many classes are using MyDbContext that created locally.

Comment: @JRTan I would recommend using a [factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) to create instances of MyDbContext. It could be tempting to use ´static´ to solve this, but be carefull. ´static´and events are a dangerous mix :)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend such a "wormhole", see my comment above.